# Como alterar paginação utilizando as teclas especificas do teclado utilizando javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Como posso executar evento de mudança de pagina utilizando javascript para que ao clicar nas setas do teclado (< ou >), execute o href dos links com ids prox-pg e ant-pg, mostrados logo abaixo.

```
<a href="url da pagina anterior" id="ant-pg"> << </a>
<a href="url da proxima pagina" id="prox-pg"> >> </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o evento "keydown". Capiture a tecla e veja se foi a tecla desejada:

```js
// associo o evento keydown
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  // se for a tecla <, "clica" o elemento "ant-pg"
  if (event.key === '<') {
    console.log("pressinaoda \<");
    document.getElementById('ant-pg').click();
  }
  // se for a tecla >, "clica" o elemento "prox-pg"
  if (event.key === '>') {
    console.log("pressionada \>");
    document.getElementById('prox-pg').click();
  }
});


function clicou(link) {
   alert("pressionado: " + link.id);
}
```

```html
<h2>Clique nessa janela para testar</h2>

<a href="#" id="ant-pg" onclick="clicou(this)"> << </a>
<a href="#" id="prox-pg" onclick="clicou(this)"> >> </a>
```

Comment: Eu executei esse exemplo que você passou, mais ao utilizar as teclas do teclado < ou > não esta funcionado.

Comment: Aqui funcionou, [veja](https://imgur.com/a/xII2EEp) . Você pressionou o SHIFT?

Comment: @Striffer qual o seu navegador? pode ser algo assim, veja que usei `javascript` puro, o `event.key` pode ser diferente